# Pyparsing - zero or one from a group

Tags: python, pyparsing

How would I get zero or only one of each tokens out of a group of tokens? They can be in any order. Say this is my code:

```
def parseFunc(self, string):
    firstToken = CaselessKeyword("KeyWordOne")
    secondToken = CaselessKeyword("KeyWordTwo")
    thirdToken = CaselessKeyword("KeyWordThree")

    stmt = ZeroOrMore(firstToken | secondToken | thirdToken)
    return stmt.parseString(string)
```

With ZeroOrMore there's a problem since every token can show multiple times. 
With Optional they have to be in exact order they are listed.

This is my current solution:

```
stmt = ZeroOrMore(firstToken | secondToken | thirdToken)
tokens = stmt.parseString(string)
s = set()
for x in tokens:
    if x[0] in s: return "Error: redundant options"
    s.add(x[0])

return tokens
```

Answer (score 6):

`Optional` is the same as "zero or one":

```
stmt = Optional(firstToken | secondToken | thirdToken)
```

There is also a new multiplication form, similar to `{min,max}` in regex:

```
stmt = (firstToken | secondToken | thirdToken) * (0,1)
```

EDIT:

For arbitrary order, use Each (defined using operator &):

```
stmt = (Optional(firstToken) & Optional(secondToken) & Optional(thirdToken))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but with optional those tokens need to be in that exact order. What I need is a possibility for those tokens to be in any order. I found a bit different solution and added it to my question.

Comment: The stmt you provided had nothing to do with exact order, it accepts *only one* of the options. See my edit.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Could it be due to older version of pyparsing (1.5.7)? ZeroOrMore, which my statement uses, does provide arbitrary order, but it also allowes for more than one of same token. That's why I added checking with set after getting tokens from parsing, which solves my problem.